# converging threads and thread priority (java)

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets pretend I have two threads running in a program. Both threads reach a node(like in a tree or map) in which the user must enter data in order for the thread to continue. Normally, if the node is synchronized, whichever thread reaches that node first will wait for input while blocking any other threads from reaching that node.

The question is:

Is there a way to accommodate thread number two (the guy being locked out) by letting him get past thread number 1? Also, is it possible to do it without causing thread 1 to quit?

I already know that you can have a time limit for entering data so that thread 1 gets closed if it sits on the node for too long but is it possible to have thread 2 "play through" so to speak?

**Never mind guys, I think I figured it out, I phrased my question poorly but thanks for trying.**

Comment: It seems that thread 2 *needs* the information thread 1 is waiting for. So how could thread 2 *go on* without that information?

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question right, the answer is `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock.tryLock()`. Just use it instead of `synchronized` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you lock (synchronize) waiting for input?

You should only lock (synchronize) when you actually go to modify something that multiple threads have access to.

**Edit:** To be more clear: The only reason thread #2 should have to wait is if:

A) It needs to modify something that thread #1 is modifying.

B) It is dependent on (needs to read) something that thread #1 is modifying.

Otherwise, you have too broad of scope on your lock.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the input is actually being written to a file.

Comment: How does that change anything? The only reason thread#2 should be blocked is if it's trying to do the same thing as thread #1, or needs to read something thread#1 is modifying.

Comment: Then how could thread #2 possibly "go by" thread #1? Do you mean you want to bail and return an error or something?

Comment: something like that, I actually just realized I phrased the question wrong. Is it possible to put threads in to a priority queue while the wait for a command or something like that?

Comment: You'd need to facilitate communication between your threads so one could tell the other to stop what it was doing and give up the lock. Or have an overseer thread to do such things. I'm still not sure it's entirely clear what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in how to code it up but Java Concurrency In Practice covers this exact scenario and how to construct it using classes in java.util.concurrent.  The book is well worth the price.

http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/